# numpy view a nested array of arrays into a 1D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

**1)** Is it possible to numpy view a nested array of arrays (with different shapes) into a 1D array:

**Input:**

```
from numpy import array as arr
a = arr([arr([arr([2,3]), arr([1])]), arr([5, 6, 7])])
```

**Output:**

```
arr([2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7])
```

**2.** Is it possible to do so with and without creating a new vector (for example np.astype vs np.view)?

Comment: It seems to me like simple `a.flatten()` is what you're looking for. Your code gives a deprecation warning and doesn't work out of the box for me, but I think that's the idea you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Examine the resulting array:

```
In [354]: a = np.array([np.array([np.array([2,3]), np.array([1])]), np.array([5,
     ...:  6, 7])])
<ipython-input-354-0bcb7871bdd4>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  a = np.array([np.array([np.array([2,3]), np.array([1])]), np.array([5, 6, 7])])
In [355]: a.shape
Out[355]: (2,)
In [356]: a[0].shape
Out[356]: (2,)
In [357]: a[1].shape
Out[357]: (3,)
```

It contains two elements, both arrays.  One has 2 elements, the other 3.  But the first itself contains 2 arrays.

We can join the 2 outer arrays with `concatenate`:

```
In [359]: np.concatenate(a)
Out[359]: array([array([2, 3]), array([1]), 5, 6, 7], dtype=object)
```

but the result is still object dtype because of the inner arrays.

We need to first clean up the inner array:

```
In [362]: a[0] = np.concatenate(a[0])
In [363]: a
Out[363]: array([array([2, 3, 1]), array([5, 6, 7])], dtype=object)
In [364]: np.concatenate(a)
Out[364]: array([2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 7])
```

This a new array, not a `view`.  The original array is object dtype.  The result is integer dtype.  There's no way to make that conversion as a view.

Comment: Thanks but This was just an example. I was asking for a general solution.

Comment: I don't know how general it has to be.  With that double nesting (or more?) it will hard, or at least tedious, to generalize.

Answer (score -1):

numpy.reshape() is the function you're looking for. It does create a new vector, but there are no workarounds that I know of to get rid of that. If you know the size of your input array, a 1D equivalent for it would be:

```
output_array = numpy.reshape(input_array, dim)
```

where dim is the number of elements in input_array. For your particular example, the display of the array would be:

```
print(numpy.reshape(a, 6))
```

Note that numpy.reshape() can be used for shapes other than 1D

Comment: Did you try it on this example in python? It doesn't work!

Comment: Well, one issue might be the fact that you don't seem to import the entirety of numpy anywhere. Another is that your construction of an array is very much deprecated due to you trying to make "a" an array composed of different size arrays